# AngularJS locale with ES6 and Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, angular-i18n

I got a problem, I work on a project with intertionalization. I'm using AngularJS 1.5, ES6, and Webpack, I also use ng-translate for the different text.

I installed AngularJS-i18n for manipulate numbers and date and AngularJS-dynamic-locale for set the $locale language when I change the website's language with npm.

The problem, I don't know how to load AngularJS locale from the node_modules in my config.js. I did this:

```
export default function configApp(thmDynamicLocaleProvider) {
   tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('../../../node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
}
configApp.$inject = ['thmDynamicLocaleProvider'];
```

I set the good URL, but I don't know why, the app returns a 404 error. And I don't know how can I load this in webpack ot others...

Answer (score 0):

If you use *webpack* i suggest you to use `import()` function. It will split the locales to chunks which will be invoked in the runtime by request. But this method has a one restriction. You can't implement dynamic way to necessary chunks. So when you'll get info from somewhere on the client side regarding current locale, you are able through `switch` operator to choose what to import.

**For example,**

```
function GetLocaleInfo(locale) {
    switch(locale) {
        case 'en': 
            import('angular-i18n/angular-locale_en.js').then((en) => {
                setLocale(en);
            });
        case 'ru': 
            import('angular-i18n/angular-locale_ru.js').then((ru) => {
                setLocale(ru);
            });  
       }
}
```

I'll pay a little bit more attention that `import` function in using on async way should have only string content. It doesn't support dynamic value cause on build step webpack check these ways to build proper chunks of code in the build directory.

**Here is** you would find more info about [code splitting on the webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/)